# Runnable thread in java and from oracle end waiting for SQL*Net message from client

Tags: database, multithreading, oracle

In our application runnable thread we are getting the below lines from thread dumps but from db end (oracle) they are getting inactive session SQL*Net message from client.

Could you please advise is it network issue or slowness or something bug in application code?

```
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
at oracle.net.ns.Packet.receive(Packet.java:311)
at oracle.net.ns.DataPacket.receive(DataPacket.java:105)
```

Comment: provide more information , which code line ? anyway might this be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28785085/how-to-prevent-hangs-on-socketinputstream-socketread0-in-java

Comment: We are facing this issue when we are saving something in database using hibernate. The issue is happening frequently. We checked with DBA and they told they are getting inactive session which is not running any query.From our end we check that there is no such query which can take long time to run.

Comment: if there is nothing running from the database side , then its from the application , can you run the application in log mode and check the applications logs and what is doing