# Why adding socket read timeout doesn't help for socketread0

Tags: java, linux, sockets, soap, timeout

My app (jdk 1.8 , on linux) makes about 1000 requests each day with several servers, using the class SOAPConnection.

The problem is that the application hangs on a native method:

```
java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
```

I have added a connection timeout and read timeout, and it helped.

**But**, about every three days, the app hangs on the socketread0 method despite the timeout I've added.

I noticed it happens in very rare cases, but when it happens, it is very critical for my application.

Comment: thanks, I understood from the answers of the question you referenced that there was a bug in Java ( by this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/32656924/3927415). Does it mean that I need to update my java version if it is now on version 1.8.0_05 ?

Comment: Sorry, I have no experience to answer this.

Comment: @user3927415 Java 1.8.0_05 (or Java 8 update 5) is ancient. The latest (public) version of Java 8 is 1.8.0_202. It is unclear by the linked issues exactly when it was fixed (as it lists a large number of backports for Java 8 update 131 to Java 8 update 192..., but I'd guess that this will mean it should be fixed in 202 at least.

Comment: currently using jdk 1.8.0_201 and I am still encountering this error